# How to build proper histogram using ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot histogram using ggplot2.

I have time series "spread" consistent of positive and negative numbers.

Ggplot keeps ploting "count" on Y-axis

My code:

```
date <- ymd("2019-01-01") + days(1:length((Price$SBER.ME)))
spread <- (stock2 - stock1)
df2 <- data.frame(date, spread)

ggplot(df2) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=spread))
```

The result:
[image]

I need to change Y-axis "count" on "volume".

I get the needed results by using `plot(spread, type='h')`:
[image: i need the same result but using ggplot2]
Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Try `geom_col(aes(x=date, y=spread))`.

Comment: What you have is a proper histogram - continuous x variable, binned, with the bin counts shown on the y axis. That's the standard definition for a histogram. What you want is a bar plot - use `geom_col` (or `geom_bar(..., stat = "identity")`)

Comment: `geom_col` is what i needed! Thanks